# send udp packets from freetronics EtherMega board

Tags: c, sockets, udp, arduino, ethernet

Hy,

i have a EtherMega board from freetronics. I try to send udp packets but i can't.

I use the sample code from aurduino:
[send udp packets](http://arduino.cc/de/Reference/EthernetUDPWrite)

On the arduino, i have a udp server and on the pc, i have a udp client. On the client i don't receive anyone.

I have been tried an other sample code from arduino:

[send and receive text strings via UDP. This one work.](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/UDPSendReceiveString)

In this sample, it is sent and received text strings via UDP. This one work.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Please can you clarify "on the client I don't receive anyone"? are you trying to receive data using udp client?

Comment: Yes, http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html

Comment: I haven't looked at the code, but you should find for how to bind your ip address and port number and how to start receiving packets. Hercules is ok utility to send udp packets. In most stacks there is a callback handler that gets called when a packet is received.